# i used 16 gb sd card for raspberry pi 2,now its showing very less memory,when i want install opencv it is showing out-of space

Tags: pi-2

[image]

i am using 16 gb sd card for raspberry pi 2.but when i want to install opencv its showing very less memory.it is unable to install.out of 16 gb only 2.9 is used then where is the rest 11 gb  memory.

Comment: Post the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0` (and DON'T post an image  but copy the text output).

Answer (score 3):

I assume that is Raspbian ?

1. `sudo raspi-config`
2. Select 1st option `Expand your file system`. Tab, tab, `finish`.
3. `sudo reboot`
4. `df -h` to see if it worked.

Additional reads : http://elinux.org/RPi_Resize_Flash_Partitions#Raspi-config

Bonus :

To install OpenCV,

1. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv`

Hope it helps. :)